# showing the whole row of a table with clicking on a link which is the title of the row?

Tags: php

The thing I want to is like the job done in many news websites. Suppose I have a table of news. Each news have title and full text. So I want to show the news in a page. I want to limit the news displayed in a page to for example three news per page (using the `limit` query which is easy) and I want to show only the titles. But I want the titles to be a link to the full text news. I mean when a user clicks on it, a new page shows up with the full text of that news. So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

news_titles.php:

```
 <?php
 //connection; then simple mysql_query and fetch (mysql is deprecated, so reconstruct it with another lib
 $sql = "SELECT id, news_content, news_title FROM news;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
  <a href="news.php?id=<?=$row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['news_title']; ?></a>
 <?php

 }   
 ?>
```

then create news.php:

```
 <?php
 //connection; then simple mysql_query and fetch (mysql is deprecated, so reconstruct it with another lib
 $sql = "SELECT id, news_content, news_title FROM news WHERE id = ". $_GET['id'] . ";";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ?>
 <p><?= $row['news_content']; ?>
 <?php

  }
 ?>
```

It will create you hyperlinks with news title's leading to news id and showing news_content in it. It will access news.php via i.e. news.php?id=5

If you get the idea, you may change some things for more security, clean and fresh code, and design

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I can't figure out this code:<?= $row['news_title']; ?> in the <a> element.Why the code starts with an ` = `?

Comment: aah, that's short from `<?php echo $row['news_title']; ?>`. However, I dislike writting PHP in HTML and vice versa :)

Answer (score 0):

A page where you echo $row['title'] linked to $row['id'] and a page which recieves $_GET['id'] = $row['id'] so it echoes $row['new'] `(SELECT`new`from news WHERE id = $_GET['id'])`

Comment: can you be a little more specific?I am a bit confused.And there is something I noticed,In news websites,when you go to a news,the php page is a totally new one.For example a page about galaxy s4 is like `galaxy-s-4.php` while a page about htc will have link like `htc-one-x.php.what's the trick in them??

Comment: They fopen() it and use the file name as a variable from the db i.e. if SELECT title FROM news WHERE id = 5 gives $row['title'] = 'Galaxy S4' they concatenate the spaces with dashes and fopen() a file with name $row['title'] where the $row['new'] is the content. However in a second answer I will try to give you and example.